# Click numbered div to show/hide table of same number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of tabs (divs) that are being automatically numbered on page load and a series of tables also being automatically numbered. What is a short jquery script to show/hide the tables based on the div clicked. Ex. "tab1" shows/hides "table1", "tab2" shows/hides "table2", etc.

I was hoping for a way to have this work for an infinite amount of these pairs, rather than writing

```
$('.tab1').click(function(){
    $('.table1').toggle();
});

$('.tab2').click(function(){
    $('.table2').toggle();
});
```

for each one

**EDIT:**

Link to example: https://jsfiddle.net/captainmorganms/o1ndn2b2/3/

Comment: Please provide the relevant extract of your HTML.

Comment: Added a relevant link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the markup provided in the example Fiddle, you can achieve this for any number of tables with a single event listener and a few extra attributes, like so:

```js
document.querySelector(".section").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var target=event.target,table;
    if(table=target.dataset.table)
        if(table=document.getElementById(table))
            table.classList.toggle("hide");
},0);
```

```css
.section>div{
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0 5px;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:3px;
}
table{
    border:1px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-top:15px;
}
table.hide{
    display:none;
}
td{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:5px;
    min-width:50px;
    height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
 <div data-table="table1">Tab1</div>
 <div data-table="table2">Tab2</div>
 <div data-table="table3">Tab3</div>
</div>
<table class="hide" id="table1">
 <tr><td>Table 1</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="hide" id="table2">
 <tr><td>Table 2</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="hide" id="table3">
 <tr><td>Table 3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var c=1;c<=your_no;c++){
  $('.tab'+c).click(function(){     
   $('.table'+$(this).attr("class").replace("tab","")).toggle(); 
  });
}
```

Just use a simple for loop for it to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.tab1,.tab2,.tab3').on('click',function(){
    $('.table'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').indexOf("tab") + 3)).toggle();
});
```

For unknow number of tables, in your case, select tabs like this:

```
$('.section div')
```

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/_jakob/o1ndn2b2/4/

I set tables hidden by default but you can remove it in CSS if you want them to be shown at start.

Comment: While a valid solution for a known number of tables, the question specifically asks for a solution for an unknown number of tables.

Comment: this is plain example to understand it better.. for unknow number he just needs to select `$('.section div')` instead of `$('.tab1,.tab2,.tab3')`